# Click Event in a adapter Class in android

Tags: android, adapter

I have a class Array Adapter in which i have 3 field  and one check box 
i wanna shw click events on each textView , my code is given Below  how to fire  click event  in this class . i am confused

```
public class ItemReportAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SalesForce>{
    private LayoutInflater li;

    public ItemReportAdapter(Context context,List<SalesForce> items){
        super(context,0,items);
        li=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        final SalesForce item=getItem(position);

        View v=convertView;
        if(v==null){
            v=li.inflate(R.layout.sfreportview,null);
        }

        final TextView idView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemID);
        if(idView!=null){
            idView.setText(""+item.getUserID());
        }

        idView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup();                
            }

            private void popup() {

                //what to write in here so as i can be shifted to other  drill down 

            }
        });

        final TextView captionView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemCaption);
        if(captionView!=null){
            captionView.setText(item.getName());
        }

        final TextView typeView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemType);
        if(typeView!=null){
            typeView.setText(item.getUserType());
        }

        final CheckBox chkbox=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes);

        chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){
                        popup();
                }

                private void popup() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        return v;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return getItem(position).getUserID();
    }
    public boolean hasStableIds(){
        return true;
    }
```

i wanna have click event on idView how can i do that ?
Any help would be appreciated Thanx!1 :)

Comment: It seems you already have click event there for idView, isn't it?

Comment: `idView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() ` isn't that your click listener? Perhaps you could rephrase your question because it sounds like you already have what you're asking for.

Comment: ManishGupta I know this is  click listner but when i wanna go the next class using intent it prohibits me to do so 
 idView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup();                
            }

            private void popup() {

what to write here so as i can be transfer to next class file

            }
        });

Comment: @ManishGupta so what can i write in the on my on Click method 
so as i can have a drill down which is my next class ?

Comment: @ManishGupta i guess u understood my problem can u help ?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume this adapter is for views inside a ListView. I see that you also have a Checkbox. Android really doesn't like having items that can be clicked or focused inside ListViews. You *can* do it but you really shouldn't. If you have a checkbox then you really want to use the "choice mode" of the ListView. See [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List11.html). If you want to perform other actions on the items you can use a long press.

Comment: Welll thnx for help but i have already done this choice mode 
this is my aarraay adapter class

Comment: i have  1 more class and i m calling array adapter class in that  classs and i have set choice mode  multiple the way you have send  me  the tutorial @dmon

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `focus` property **"false"** for the entire row, then it should work.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add focus "TRUE" for textView "idView" also.

Comment: Your textView should have focus, it should not be override by any other controls

Answer (score 0):

You should make listview with holder and i think your click event should work . But here is another code you can try.. I wrote mine. But you can follow it.

```
class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<LatestFeedInfo> m_list = new ArrayList<LatestFeedInfo>();

    public FeedListAdapter(ArrayList<LatestFeedInfo> list) {
        m_list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return m_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return m_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = li.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
            rowView.setTag(holder);

            holder.txtFeedUrl = (TextView) rowView

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        final LatestFeedInfo feed = m_list.get(position);
        holder.txtFeedUrl.setText(Html.fromHtml(feed.Activity));

        holder.txtFeedUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here is the click event
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtFeedUrl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

refer the follwing answer which is similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237375/607968

Problem with click events insdie adapter view items is that you will not know, which child item was clicked. What you are interested in is the `getTag()` and `setTag()` functions, which enable you to know which view is clicked. Notice how we set the position as the tag for the view, and retrieve the position inside `onClick`.  The same is true for handling click events for any child item inside an adapter view item.

Comment: i need to click events one on checkbox and other on the textviews present in the listactivity

Comment: please refer the link. It explains how to handle chekbox events in a list viwe.